# Is std::lock_guard<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>> valid or recommended?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to assert on unique_lock::owns_lock() in a working method, but I dont' want to pass the unique_lock as an argument but use it as a static variable. But that means I cannot use the unique_lock for its RAII behavior.
Would it be fair to have code like:

```
namespace
{
    std::mutex gMtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> gLock(gMtx, std::defer_lock);
}

void foo()
{
    assert(gLock.owns_lock());
    // ...
}

void bar()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>> lock(gLock);
    //...
    foo();
    //...
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This does and appears to work.

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <mutex>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    namespace
    {
        mutex gMtx;
        unique_lock<mutex> gLock(gMtx, defer_lock);
    }

    void foo(const string& msg)
    {
        assert(gLock.owns_lock());
        cout << msg << endl;
    }

    void bar()
    {
        lock_guard<unique_lock<mutex>> lock(gLock);
        foo("bar()");
    }

    int main()
    {
        bar();
        return 0;
    }

Comment: As workaround, you could change the mutex to recursive_mutex, and lock it in `foo()` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard is unclear about the validity of this construct.

The template parameter of `std::lock_guard` must meet [BasicLockable requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable), i.e. it must have functions `lock()` and `unlock()`.

`std::unique_lock` has these functions, which means the code compiles. However, they do not work as BasicLockable requires. `unlock()` should throw no exceptions, but `std::unique_lock::unlock()` can throw exceptions. According to this, using `std::lock_guard<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>>` should be undefined behavior.

However, as [Holt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2666289/holt) points out in comments, the standard also says that `unique_lock` meets the BasicLockable requirements. So it is unclear whether the behavior is defined. If you can guarantee that `unlock()` does not throw (the mutex is not unlocked anywhere before `lock_guard` is destroyed), it will probably work in practice.

Comment: There is a note in the standard that says *"[ Note: `unique_lock<Mutex>` meets the `BasicLockable` requirements. [...] ]"*, but as you pointed out, the `std::unique_lock::unlock` does not meet the `BasicLockable::unlock` requirement, which is kind of strange...

Comment: I posted this apparent conflict to the [std-discussion](https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-discussion?place=msg%2Fstd-discussion%2F7FELSZvOX3c%2FHbsrjeSNCAAJ) mailing list. My feeling (before seeing any answers) is that it's fine, as the only way for `std::unique_lock::unlock()` to throw is if it [doesn't own the lock](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.lock.unique#locking-26.1), and `BasicLockable` has a prerequisite for calling `unlock()` that the [current execution agent owns the lock](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.lockable.basic#3).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be valid, according to the current [C++ standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread), and the same text applies in [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/) with only one paragraph-numbering change.

[The thing passed as the template argument to `std::lock_guard` must be a `BasicLockable`](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.lock.guard#1).

[`BasicLockable`](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.lockable.basic) specifies two things:

1. `lock()`, which has no requirements or limitations beyond either acquiring the lock *or* throwing an exception.
2. `unlock()`, which can only be called if the lock is held, cannot fail, and **cannot throw an exception**.

[`unique_lock::lock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.lock.unique#locking-1) appears to satisfy the first clause, but see below the separator line.

[`unique_lock::unlock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.lock.unique#locking-23) satisfies the requirements of the second clause, on the basis that the only circumstance under which `unique_lock::unlock` may throw is if the lock is not currently held, and `BasicLockable` requires that the lock is held when `unlock` is called.

This matches the only response I received when I posited this reading to the [isocpp.org std-discussion](https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-discussion?place=msg%2Fstd-discussion%2F7FELSZvOX3c%2FHbsrjeSNCAAJ) mailing list.

---

If the `unique_lock` is already held, it appears that the requirement for `BasicLockable` is violated, as the current [execution agent](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread#req.lockable.general-1) holds the lock, *and* an exception is thrown. Since the exact wording is

> If an exception is thrown then a lock shall not have been acquired for the current execution agent.

one could argue that the lock wasn't *acquired*, as it was already held.